# Windows 8 System Restore not working automatically

Tags: windows-8

This is related to Windows 8 in general, it happens on 8 x64 Pro as well as 8.1 x64 Pro both of which I have had available form MSDN and Dreamspark.

The first thing is that System Restore is not activated by default. Not sure if this is standard to Windows 8 or just an MSDN/Dreamspark thing, so I changed the setting to allocate 10% onto my main drive (Approx 60GB).

I have installed various applications and Windows updates and there is only one single restore point that was created when the first set of critical updates were installed.

But I have installed a number of applications like Office and have done other installations in the mean time. I expected many more restore points.

Windows 7 used to create so many restore points I needed to clean them. I don't want to have to remember to manually create them or set up a task. I'd just like it to work more like it did before.

So is there a way to fix this non-creation of system restore points? At the least so that installing updates and new software trigger the creation as it feels like Windows is ignoring it

Comment: Where is the question?  By default Windows will create a restoration point when updates are installed or when an the install of a program does so.  Most Microsoft software does it.

Comment: @Ramhound Updated the qustion slightly. The problem is that these restore points are not being created on installation where I expect they should be.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by [this document](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) you are right in suggesting that restores don't happen for as many reasons. Currently I have programs that create system restore points when I update them. Windows 8 still has the features to create the restore point manually, I would suggest doing this once a week. 

I don't want to speculate, but I would suppose that Microsoft intends for you to use either refresh or reset to fix system problems. The theory being here that most programs provide only online activation and provide their keys through online accounts making it much easier to rebuild a system. Also many personal settings will sync to your Windows Live account. 
If you are using the 8.1 Preview (I am) you might have noticed that your updates are few and far between. This could result in fewer restores.

Comment: I am on 8.1 (release not preview). That document you link seems to explain some of the expected behaviour regarding the 7 days. I expected it to be a system restore every time you update, I guess this is no longer the behaviour. However installing new applications I hoped restore would happen as usual but maybe not.